# How to add a dependency constraint to a grade project from a custom gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

How to add a dependency constraint to a project from a custom gradle plugin?

I want to create a gradle plugin that will constrain transitive dependencies in the project the plugin is applied to. Ideally, I want this plugin to follow the following rules:

- Only try and apply a constraint to a project if the it exists in the project. E.g. only apply a constraint on dependency X if dependency X is pulled into the project.
- Apply the constraints automatically on application of the plugin, I don't want to create/run an extra task or anything like that.
- (Bonus) Don't apply the constraints to primary dependencies, only transitive dependencies.

Here's what I have so far.

```
class ConstraintPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    private Map<String, String> constraintMap = [
            "jackson-core": "2.13.2",
            "logback-classic": "2.3.9"
    ]

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.configurations.each {config ->
            config.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {dep ->
                if (constraintMap.containsKey(dep.name)) {
                    ModuleVersionIdentifier id = dep.moduleVersion.id
                    String constraintVersion = constraintMap.get(id.name)

                    DependencyConstraint dc = new DefaultDependencyConstraint(id.group, id.name, constraintVersion)

                    config.dependencyConstraints.add(dc)
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using a map instantiated within the constraint plugin class with the names of the dependencies I want to constrain along with the versions to constrain to in the project this plugin is applied to. Here I want to constrain the `jackson-core` and `logback-classic` dependencies.

My first thought was to run through each configuration and see if that dependency name is present within that configuration. If so, create a new `DependencyConstraint` and add it to the configuration. However this is *not* working when I apply the plugin to another project.

Also note I am not disregarding primary dependencies quite yet, this feature is more like a "nice to have" at this point, I haven't figured out how to only look at transitive dependencies within a given configuration.

I think my issue lies with how I am applying the new `DependencyConstraint` programmatically but I can't seem to find a way to add a constraint that works. The only other way I've tried is `project.dependencies.constraints.create(dc)` which also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but why don't you simply use constraints definitions in your build.gradle? It seems to satisfy all your needs.
Your approach of manually creating dependency constraints is not working because you're doing it *after* the dependency set is resolved and all the constraints are applied. You can do something like this to manualy add a constraint to be resolved further:

```
class ConstraintsPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    private Map<String, String> constraintMap = [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core": "2.13.5"
    ]

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.configurations.each {config ->
                if (config.canBeDeclared) {
                    constraintMap.each { module, version ->
                        def constraint = project.dependencies.constraints.create("${module}:${version}")
                        config.dependencyConstraints.add(constraint)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: ConstraintsPlugin

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:9.0.0'
}
```

Now if you run this command with and without applying a plugin, you'll see the difference in jackson-core versions resolved.

```
./gradew dependencyInsight --dependency jackson-core
```

But this is a rough version of just declaring a dependency constraint.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does work! I wouldn't expect to have a bunch of constraints added, so afterEvaulate is probably okay to use. I've read that it can be quite expensive. 

Why do we need to check if the configuration can be declared? If it is there (And we are using `afterEvaluate`), can we just assume each configuration is declared and valid? 

Great suggestion though thank you! I am working on creating a plugin that can declare similar constraints across multiple buildscripts to reduce redundancy so this will definitely help!